# How to upload images from client side to server side and retrieve them dynamically

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am completely new about uploading files. Is there any way to upload image by user on my website and when other users view that website those images will be shown to them. This is something like various websites where user post ad with images and when other users view that post can also view images.

Tried to store and retrieve them into/from database, but loading of images is too slow. I want to store them in a folder on server, and when that particular post is viewed then those images should be retrieve.

Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: what framework you are using?

Comment: Refer This Link.   http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-file-upload-save-tutorial-with-example/     . with this store your uploaded path in database and load image related to that post.

Comment: I hope you have already implemented UploadServlet. If not, have a look at : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm.  Instead of storing the image on database, store image in file system of webserver, which is a document root to show images to others, If your jsp server & image view server are different, have an NFS mount

Comment: Is there any way to use only jsp, without struts. Just for knowledge. I know there is, but i am not getting them.

Comment: If you are looking at help for uploading of file, this link is also useful. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/file-upload-example-in-servlet-and-jsp.html

Comment: Yes. Without struts & with JSP alone, you can do it. The above link shows the same

Comment: Thanks got it. But, can I store images with a predefined/custom name? Like, when some one upload an image to his post, it have to save with name like: (postid-imageno) 
Ex- postid=65524
      imageno=2
So- 65524-2

I want this so that i can retrieve them easily using loop.

Comment: you can rename the file and save as per your config.

Comment: And what about other input elements? As Multipartcontent will not allow me to get those values of input tags. I'll get null.

Comment: @SanjayPatel  I don't want to hardcode the file name. file name have to be change acc to previous example. A user can upload many images to that post one by one.

Comment: you can try like this way.---->>>>int i=1;
   String dir="c:\\upload\\";
   String filename=i+".txt";
   File f=new File(dir+filename);   extra changes neede as per your requirement.
   
   if(f.exists()){
    i++;
    filename=i+".txt";
    f=new File(dir+filename);
    f.createNewFile();
   }else{
    f.createNewFile();
   }

Answer (score 0):

index.php:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <lable>select a file to upload ... </lable>
  <input type="file" name="imageupload" required>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_FILES['imageupload'])) {
      $imagename = $_FILES['imageupload']['name'];
      $imagetemp = $_FILES['imageupload']['tmp_name'];
    }
    if (!$imagetemp) {
        echo "you need to select a file to upload";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($imagetemp, "upload/$imagename");
    }
 ?>
```

now enough insert this location to database:

```
   INSERT INTO `database name`.`table name` (`filde name`) VALUES ('[domain address]/upload/$imagename');
```

Comment: Not php. Is there other way in jsp?